# How to insert newline in "caption" attribute through Facebook Graph API wall post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've seen apps post links with "captions" to user's walls and they have a newline in them.  Foursquare is one of these apps.

I cannot figure out how to get a newline recognized and I've tried everything, including just passing in "\r\n", "\n", etc.

(note: I'm talking about publishing to a user's wall -- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the way to do this easily is to provide both `caption` and `description` parameters with the HTTP POST. Caption will be the first line, and Description will act as the second.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
<center></center>
```

as part of your caption string. It will create a line-break for you when posting the link.

Comment: This will make a newline but it centers that next line which isn't what I was looking for.

Comment: Did you try it?
It does not center the text in my facebook-app
`this is line one<center></center>this is line two´

Comment: Still works to this date. The center tag isn't stripper and is by default block-level, so if you make sure to close it, it should just force a line-break like as if there was a random DIV inserted. Pretty hacky though...

Answer (score 0):

Try using properties arguments in graph api:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?message=he&access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>&properties={1:{'text':'something',href='http://www.example.com'},2:{'text':'anything',href='http://www.example.com'}}
```

This will publish post in 2 lines... 
(Note: json should be converted to string before processing)

Comment: Neat, didn't know that there was a properties argument in graph API. Do you know where the docs are for this? Can you also clarify your example? Why is there an href argument for both attributes?

Comment: Href is for hyperlink to every text your write to next line... For doc... i found it from googling only... not specific doc :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using only description instead of caption.